# Is there a Salesforce formula playground website / service / tool

Tags: unit-test, formula

I'm interested in using a Salesforce formula playground similar to:

- [JS Bin - JavaScript Debugger](https://jsbin.com/?html,output)
- [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

I've had a Google and cannot find anything.

Does anyone know of a tool/website/service similar but for Salesforce formulas?

Comment: The development environment is the only place I can think of.

Comment: Formula Field Editor is a playground itself...Salesforce is not like Javascript ...it's gated and each org has it's own configuration. I don't think there should be any such tool.

Comment: Just create a formula field that is accessible only to you and you can play around all that you want.

Comment: In Salesforce, we don't have a feature *specifically* like this. That said, you can create Scratch Orgs, Developer Orgs, and Sandboxes to play around with various features to your heart's content. Such a tool like JS Fiddle would be meaningless in Salesforce, because you'd still have to set up a data model, define permissions, etc, all the stuff you'd do in a regular org anyways.

Comment: @sfdcfox if we imagine a tool called 'SF Fiddle' ... to use it, you need to authenticate against an org, this would give you the data model. But even in an anonymous mode, you could still test date functions...

Comment: @Robs Cool idea, I guess, but it'd probably be a lot of work, since we can't call the function engine directly, we'd end up having to simulate everything. This is in contrast to JS fiddle, which lets the browser handle 99% of the work, with it just acting as a sort of simplistic compiler.

Comment: @sfdcfox 100% agree. shame the Tooling API doesn't let you submit a formula for evaluation...

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, someone has created a sort of formula playground at "[formulon.io](https://formulon.io)"

EDIT:  Today I've found out about this other tool (AppExchange package by Jakub Stefaniak):  [Formula Debugger](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000G6g5PUAR)